# How can I back up my app data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I have some app data that I'd like to preserve when the time for a new iPhone rolls around.  This app does not (seem to) have any cloud-syncing functionality.  I regularly sync my iPhone to iTunes via USB on a Macbook Air running OS X 10.5.8.  How can I ensure that this app's data is backed up, so as to re-use it on a new device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you take a full backup of your iPhone (right click on it in iTunes and choose **Back Up**) and then restore it to a new phone, all data will be preserved, including apps' data:

> iTunes will back up the following information
>
> - Contacts* and Contact Favorites (regularly sync contacts to a computer or cloud service such as iCloud to back them up).
> - App Store Application data including in-app purchases (except the Application itself, its tmp and Caches folder).
> - **Application settings, preferences, and data, including documents.**

From iTunes: [About iOS backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946).

Comment: Is this information still valid? I am currently trying to transfer app data from an old device running iOS 7 to a new device running iOS 8, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not everything is backed up, according to this [apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136)

Answer (score 6):

Vlad's answer is good, and he's absolutely right.

An alternative to iTunes would be to use an iOS device browser. This would be especially good if you only wanted to back up *one app's data* rather than the whole device. Options of these include [Phone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/) and [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

Comment: I'd also add CopyTrans Apps if you are on Windows: http://www.copytrans.net/copytransapps.php

Comment: iTunes does not backup *everything*. It leaves out some data for some apps. The only way I know for sure to truly save *all* app data is to use iMazing (formerly named DiskAid) to export each app individually from the old phone and reinstall each app individually on the new phone.

Answer (score 3):

**To [backup your device to iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766)**:

1. Launch the **Settings** app.
2. Go to **iCloud > Backup & Storage**.
3. If you enable **iCloud Backup** all your data will automatically be backed up each night.
4. Or you can press **Back Up Now** to immediately perform a backup of all your data.

**To restore your data to the same phone**:

1. Make sure you backed up and that the backup completed successfully.
2. Delete all data on the phone by going to **Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings**. -- **WARNING:** This will delete all your data, so make sure you have it backed up, especially anything not syncing to iCloud.
3. Follow the steps below for a new phone.

**To restore your data to a new Phone:**

1. During the **Setup Assistant**, choose to **Restore from iCloud Backup**.

**Notes:**

- This will only work if you have less than 5 GB of data on the device. Otherwise you will need to buy more space from Apple or choose to not sync certain things (e.g. Photos and Videos). If do the latter, realize that when you erase all your settings all that data will be gone unless you copied it somewhere else besides iCloud.

Comment: But since OS X 10.5.8 is too old to run iCloud, I wouldn't be able to retrieve the backed-up data and put it on my new iPhone??

Comment: @KatieK: You actually don't need a computer to restore the data on to a new phone. It takes it all from iCloud. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jailbreak on your device, you can use "Apps Manager" tweak (https://repo.xarold.com/pack/appdatamanager) to locally backup/restore data by app. It works fine even on iOS 10 and 11.

Answer (score -3):

Only the best thing to save data is icloud

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please provide more of an answer when answering questions.  Adding supporting info will help the OP and others who might have the same issue.  Please see this FAQ for [answer].  - From Review -

Answer (score -4):

i dont know about i cloud but with itunes it back ups everything